# How much RAM does a simple portfolio website need?

Tags: webserver, vps

I'm trying to make a portfolio site for myself and my programming projects. Because I'm also going to be making a few other websites for friends and family members, I've opted for VPS.

I was wondering, however - how much RAM would I need? None of these websites will have any particularly taxing software running on it, nor do I expect a large amount of users. (The basic plan at the host I'm looking at is 300 MB, which I'm guessing is enough.)

Comment: There's no way to know given this information, and it's off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.  Your best bet is to secure a reasonable amount and add to it when needed.

Comment: I think it's probably an impossible question to answer without knowing specifics about what you are going to host (If you just need to run a LAMP server with some wordpress blogs versus hosting several large rails applications). I'd say go for the 300MB instance, see how it performs, and scale up if you need to.

Comment: I'd assert that being concerned of RAM is wholly needless.  A *portfolio* is simple display of your accomplishments and the hosting of small websites for friends and family members all can be solved with shared-hosting solutions that are one-tenth the cost and perfectly suited for what a portfolio/family website should expect in traffic and bandwidth usage.

Comment: It'll likely be a LAMP type thing, I won't be running any large applications. I was just trying to see if there was something I wasn't accounting for that might come back and bite me in the ass. Thanks, DVG and hexparrot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you'll need less than you might think.  Serving up a page, especially a simple page with only a little business logic, doesn't require much RAM for most servers.  When you start serving up computational taxing pages, movies, high quality sound files, etc, then you might notice an increased server load.

My suggestion would be to go with the smallest / cheapest usable plan.  Monitor your usage the first while to gauge typical traffic and usage.  At that point, you can decide whether an upgrade is necessary given your circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently hosting 10 WordPress and other sites on a VPS that used to have 256MB of RAM, but was recently upgraded to 512 by the host. The sites get between 10 and 500 hits a day, and I do run some caching on the WP sites. I had no problems with the 256MB of RAM on the VPS that I'm running. Based on your description, it sounds like you'll be fine. If you do see yourself running out of resources, things like object caching will make your life a lot easier without having to pay more for a beefier VPS.